# Which web services should be integrated?

Tags: web, integration

Mail + Social networking?

One identity for all sites?

Integration between all social networks and IM services?

Which web services should be integrated in the future, and why?

**Edit: Clarification:**

By "integrating", I mean that two or more services should be seamlessly connected, and that connection would benefit the user. Foe example, I would really like to have an IM application that would support many accounts on many IM providers (And IMHO, Pidgin's not ready yet).

Comment: Please make this a community wiki. This question has no concrete answer

Comment: "integrated" into what? Could you please specify what exactly do you mean by that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail/IM/Social Networking: [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com/) offers to solve some of this.

One identify for all sites: [OpenID](http://openid.net/) is on its way to solving this too.

I look forward to having my contacts and communication (more) centralised. APIs for various web services help with this, you can have local datastores that combine all the data.

Comment: I see Google Wave as change of platform, service, and architecture of how we think about email, messaging, and other social media aspects.

Answer (score 1):

From the standpoint of the user of the services integration has many advantages.
Imagine you have to log into only one site with only a single set of credentials and you can send mail, post blog articles and tweets and so on.

I don't expect this to happen, though.

One reason for this is that there is competition between companies and there will be no single company that can ever offer the best service for everybody.
Some specialize in social networks (i.e. facebook), some in microblogging (i.e. twitter), some try to provide the best blogging  platform (i.e. wordpress.com)...

Another reason is that this is also good for the users ultimately, because they can choose from a multitude of services what suits them best.

---

My opinion is that I don't expect that integration to happen and I think this is ultimately good for us customers.

Answer (score 1):

Integration of various IM providers, has been done very well with Meebo, albeit only as a web app.

What I'm looking for is something that will take my various IM account credentials, social networks, phone and Mac Address book contacts, and then consolidate my contacts, with each contact containing their name, email address/IM user name on the various networks (Gmail, hotmail, yahoo), date of birth (from facebook), phone number (from address books), and usernames for the various social networks.

Then, if I wanna contact any of them, I look up the contact on that site. If the person is online on any of the IM/Social networks, it will let me chat with them from there. Otherwise, it'll show the email address and phone number, leaving it up to me to decide which medium of contact to use.

Lastly, it should sync the relevant consolidated data to all my softwares / devices.
This is my dream web app